# one hot encoding with multiple categorical values per row in python

Tags: python, one-hot-encoding

I want to implement one hot encoding to a categorical feature in python 3.
I notice that few of the id's have more than one categorical value.

My table:

```
id  type
13   A
13   B
2    A
34   C
34   A
34   B
```

My desire output:

```
id  type@A  type@B  type@C
13     1      1       0
2      1      0       0
34     1      1       1
```

what can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ok using pandas, store the data in a dataframe (name `df` for example) and use :

```
pd.crosstab(df['id'],df['type']).rename_axis(None,axis=1)
```

Example below:

```
import pandas as pd
d={'id': {0: 13, 1: 13, 2: 2, 3: 34, 4: 34, 5: 34},
'type': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'A', 3: 'C', 4: 'A', 5: 'B'}}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

   id type
0  13    A
1  13    B
2   2    A
3  34    C
4  34    A
5  34    B
```

Using [`pd.crosstab()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
df_new = pd.crosstab(df['id'],df['type']).rename_axis(None,axis=1).add_prefix('type@')
print(df_new)

     type@A  type@B  type@C
id                        
2        1       0       0
13       1       1       0
34       1       1       1
```

Comment: I edited my question. I need it to be type@A as a col name. with your solution I get a lot of rows, there is a problem.

Comment: I have edited so column names match your desired output. What do you mean by "a lot of rows", can you demonstrate that in your question. Thanks

Comment: I change the "desire output" to what I exactly looking for. can you change your solution to match it?

Comment: @anat the same code still works, can you recheck with just the data you have posted. i have posted the data i am getting with your edited question.

Comment: are you concerned about the order of the rows? meaning `id` 2 comes before `13` is that the problem?

Comment: yes. I tried your solution and in the result DF there was more rows than unique ids. also I need the id to remain a col.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187805/discussion-between-anky-91-and-anat).